# Give HDInsight cluster access to all the folders of an ADL Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake, data-lake

I am trying to add an ADL Storage (ADLS) account to my HDInsight cluster.
1) I have created a Service Principal (SP) using Azure Active Directory (AAD)
2) I granted this SP access as a contributor to the ADLS account
3) I am now trying to use this SP to create a HDInsight cluster

It seems that the SP still doesn't have the proper access [no access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eldde.png)

I guess the solution is to grant manually, to the SP, access to each folder I need in the Data Explorer.
However, my storage account contains a huge list of folders, thus the request to add all the sub-folders take ages (+10h). Moreover, new folders are constantly added every day, thus I can't rely on this operation.

Is there a way to grand the SP access to the root folder and all its subfolders at once?

Answer (score 0):

**To assign permission at the Data Lake Store account root level**:

1. On the **Data Lake Store access** blade, click Access. The **Select file
   permissions** blade is opened. It lists all the Data Lake Store
   accounts in your subscription.
2. Hover (do not click) the mouse over the name of the Data Lake Store
   account to make the check box visible, then select the check box.

   By default, **READ**, **WRITE**, AND **EXECUTE** are all selected.

[image]

3. Click **Select** on the bottom of the page.
4. Click **Run** to assign permission.
5. Click **Done**

Comment: Thanks, I understand that after granting permission to a folder and its subfolders, the rule will be persistent and apply with every new subfolder that is added later.

Comment: However, in my situation, the folder contains tens of thousands of subfolders, therefore the "Run" can take hours, even days.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is adlstool its a very effective way to apply the permissions to the folders to the adls files/folders.
You can able to apply permissions to over a million files in 10 minutes.

Comment: Generally, tool or library recommendations [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.